# Load-balanced site frequently losing permalink settings

Tags: permalinks, hyperdb

There's an intermittent issue where the permalinks are suddenly lost on the site. Going in to wp-admin and saving `Settings->Permalinks` (without changing anything) always fixes it, but I can't figure out why it loses those settings in the first place.

The site on an AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance: responsively scaling servers, along with separate read-write and read-only database servers, handled with HyperDB. When traffic is high, the site can scale up to being load-balanced across as many as a dozen servers. At low traffic, it's usually on just 2. If you're not familiar with EB architecture, the takeaway is that it effectively 'creates' and 'destroys' servers as it scales up and down (but the DB servers are always constant - it's only the web servers that scale). Server admins confirmed that there was high traffic over the weekend, and the site briefly scaled up to 10 servers before scaling back down, but we honestly don't know if that's the issue or a coincidence.

I can't figure out how or why permalink settings are being lost. I've taken a look at the codebase and there's only one custom plugin that calls `flush_rewrite_rules()`, and it calls it on plugin activation only. There are a few other plugins that call it, but they're all 'big' ones (e.g. WooCommerce, Download Monitor, Yoast), so I doubt they're the issue. The `.htaccess` file is in the repo and should be built out to every server at point of scale (and besides, if it failed to build on one server, it shouldn't affect all the others, but that's definitely happening: permalinks are out across the board).

Is there any other reason this to happen? Could it be a consequence of the servers scaling in this way?

Answer (score 0):

This points to an issue with `.htaccess`. Going to `Settings->Permalinks` will recreate `.htaccess`, and so I think that it could be an issue with file permissions during your load or maybe because it's a dot file the server could be treating the file differently and somehow deleting it?

This maybe useful :

I have a routine that runs `flush_rewrite_rules(true)` on deployment of my theme. I use `wp-cli` (https://wp-cli.org/) to trigger this:

```
// in functions.php  (using closures)
add_action('cli_init', function () {
  WP_CLI::add_command('deploy', function () {
    flush_rewrite_rules(true);
    // do something else.
  });
});
```

As part of my deployment process I use the following commands in my CI/CD process

```
cd \path\to\wp_root
php wp-cli.phar deploy
```

That way your `.htaccess` file will be recreated every time your deploy.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - that looks like a good routine to implement. But there is an `.htaccess` file in the source already, and the issue doesn't come up during deployment (i.e. when we build the servers out), or even every time they scale (they scaled yesterday with no problems) - it seems to be random. Currently waiting for it to happen again to see if we can figure out what's going on, but I may implement this regardless 

Comment: Could just be some permission issue screwing things up.

Comment: We've actually been investigating this just now and there's definitely something screwy going on, as the .htaccess on one server was created new yesterday, while on the other server it hasn't been updated since October (and in fact has different directives). The servers shouldn't be able to update their own .htaccess files (because they're load-balanced) so we're updating the permissions right now to make them non-writable. Doesn't answer everything, but it's definitely a step in the right direction.